# moderate size of the data sample

Tags: estimation, sample-size, methodology, philosophical

It is often that the authors of papers in AI, ML and Statistics write that their methods are proved to perform good for "moderate sample sizes". I saw this statement in very high ranking journals.

Could you, please, explain what is the meaning of this rather blurry statement. I would appreciate any thoughts about this.

For example, we are dealing with $m$-dimensional multivariate normal distribution. What could be "the moderate" $n$ in this case?

Comment: Without further elaboration, such non-quantitative statements are meaningless and useless.  Their intended meanings will vary with the context, discipline, and purpose of the procedure, too.